# black box testing chat applicationc#

Tags: c#, black-box-testing

I have server chat application written on C#, that just receives the messages from the sender. I need to do black box testing. I researched on the internet and found that black-box testing is just a testing of input and output, but there is no real example how to do it in an application. Can someone suggest how I would do black-box testing on my chat application?

Comment: surely if its a requirement for the project you've covered it somewhat in course material

Comment: no, I'm exchange student, and have studied only one semester in this university, they had covered it in last semesters.. But in my home univeristy I've never did that..

Comment: If ever somebody looks at this question, here I have a useful link for you man: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx#bkmk_use_unit_tests_to_improve_your_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black box testing is exactly like you said, testing input and output.  Think of it like the black box audio recorders found in commercial airplanes.  The input it allows is audio, the output would be nothing except maybe an indicator that allows the user to see that it is working.

With an application it is the same thing.  Ask yourself, are there buttons you can press, can the window be resized; overall, what components are in the application.

Something my professor always did was smash on the keyboard and see if the application was affected.  That is keyboard input, and see if anything out of the ordinary happened--like the system failing.  If the application just receives messages, you need to come up with a way to send it messages to test it.  You need to consider the cases of sending it null strings, sending different messages with different encodings, you have to send it very large messages.  When you do these things, you record what their output is and if the application passed or failed.  From that point you know what needs is wrong with the system and can make changes from there.

In short, think of any inputs that would affect the application (mouse clicks, keyboard smashing, sending it messages) and then record what the outputs are.  Use the outputs to determine if a test passed or failed.  In your case, you're going to want to write another small application that can connect to the server and send it valid/invalid data to see how your server responds to it.